# Why doesn't COUNT(DISTINCT (*)) work?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am still surprised why such simple query is not working:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT *) FROM dbo.t_test
```

Where as

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT col1) FROM dbo.t_test
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM dbo.t_test
```

works.

What is the alternative?

EDIT:

`DISTINCT *` checks for uniqueness for the combined key of (col1,col2,...) and returns those rows. I expected COUNT(DISTINCT *) to just return number of such rows. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: What "is not working"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The truth of the matter is that SQL (Server) or any other SQL implementation is **not supposed to do everything** under the sun.

There are reasons to limit the SQL syntax to certain elements, from the parsing layer to query optimization to predictability of results to just common sense.

The COUNT aggregate function is normally implemented as a streaming aggregate with a gate for a single item, be it `*` (record count, just use a static token), or `colname` (increment token only when not null) or `distinct colname` (a hash/bucket with one key).

When you ask for `COUNT(DISTINCT *)` or for that matter, `COUNT(DISTINCT a,b,c)` - yes, it can surely be done for you if some RDBMS sees fit to implement it one day; but it is (1) uncommon enough (2) adds work to the parser (3) adds complexity to the COUNT implementation.

Mark has [the correct alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010470/why-doesnt-countdistinct-work/5010485#5010485).

Answer (score 22):

It doesn't work because you are only allowed to specify a single expression in `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` as per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx):

```
COUNT ( { [ [ ALL | DISTINCT ] expression ] | * } )
```

If you look carefully you can see that the allowed grammar *doesn't* include `COUNT(DISTINCT *)`.

The alternative is this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM dbo.t_test 
) T1
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what the others have said:

One thing to be aware of is that doing a `count(distinct *)` (if it was allowed) on a table that has a primary key would be identical to a `select count(*)`.

This is because *distinct ** includes the PK column and therefor every row is distinct from every other row.

And as every non-trivial table should have a primary key (there are only **very** few exceptions to that rule) `count(distinct *)` can be "replaced" with `count(*)` anyway.

Answer (score 4):

As a simple example, let's say you have two columns, A and B.

```
A    B
1    100
2    100
3    100
```

There are three distinct A values, but only one distinct B value. It would be impossible for `COUNT(DISTINCT *)` to return a single, meaningful value. That is why that syntax cannot work.

Comment: Thanks Joe! I updated the question regarding your explanation.

Answer (score -1):

I had a same problem, finally make this solution

think you have something like this

| PID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | milk |
| 1 | cheese |
| 1 | tea |
| 2 | butter |
| 2 | cream |
| 3 | honey |

and your table was named "food"
you will code like this

```
    select distinct count(dbo.food.PID) as count,a.PID from dbo.food
    inner join (select distinct dbo.food.PID as PID from db.food) a       
on dbo.food.PID=a.PID where a.PID=dbo.food.PID 
 group by a.PID,dbo.food.PID
```

this will show something like this

| count | PID |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |

Comment: How does this answer the question? It's doesn't explain anything about the DINSTINCT operator, which is what is asked. Also, this is an incredibly contrived way to do a simple group by + count and there's even a typo in the output.